# IndexError when trying to execute a Script

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out why this

```
def scanner(fileName, function):
    with open(fileName) as file:
        for line in file:
            function(line)

def toSmallLetters(line):
    print line.lower()

def paramin(fileName):
    scanner(fileName, toSmallLetters)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    paramin(sys.argv[1])
```

throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 14, in <module>
    paramin(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Do you know what `sys.argv` is? How are you running your script?

Comment: How are you executing the script, You must pass the argument from command line

Comment: I'm executing the script from the cmd line. The path is correct and all is good except for the code, which I assume is wrong somewhere.

Comment: @PedroCarvalho: no, the code is not wrong. Take a look at the [documentation for `sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv), see if you can work out what it is supposed to do. Take into account that in Python indexing starts at *zero*.

Comment: if I index at 0 then I get another error saying the object is not iterable

Comment: @PedroCarvalho: I didn't say you needed to change that index. The code is *not wrong*. But you are *using* the code wrong.

Comment: @PedroCarvalho It's better not to use words like 'function' in the parameters. It'll only cause confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 14, in <module>
    paramin(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

because when you run the script you need to supply a parameter, presumably the file name that you want to scan. If the file is called `script.py` you might run as:

```
python script.py name-of-file-to-scan
```